# ¡Conozcan a nuestro segundo moderador: Luiggi Mendoza!

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Mientras el sitio crece, la necesidad de aumentar nuestro equipo de moderación también lo hace. Recientemente, tuve el placer de hablar con uno de nuestros miembros, **[Luiggi Mendoza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza)** - que por cierto sale en nuestro **[segundo webcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zd-YYaEYdg4)** - y empezamos a discutir un poco sobre el futuro del sitio.  Me gustaron las ideas y la energía que proporciono y me quede pensando que seria una buena adición al equipo.  Luiggi también quiere ver que esta comunidad sea un gran éxito y esta listo para apoyar a nuestra membresía y a nuestros visitantes.

Al igual que a **[Konamiman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman)**, le pedi una breve biografía para compartir con ustedes.  Sin más demoras, les presento a nuestro segundo moderador:

> ### Luiggi Mendoza es…
>
> Un joven muy curioso amante del [Perú](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per%C3%BA) que siempre cuestiona el por qué de varias cosas. Desde pequeño (entre los 3 y 4 años de edad) sintió mucha curiosidad de cómo una supuesta caja gris podía conectarse a un televisor para mostrar personajes pintorescos y medio cuadrados y que mediante un control le podía dar órdenes. Luego aprendió que el nombre de esa caja misteriosa se llamaba [Nintendo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Entertainment_System) y que el personaje cuadriculado que manejaba se llamaba [Mario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_(personaje)). Esta primera curiosidad sería la raíz de su gusto por los video juegos y, posteriormente, al mundo del software y el desarrollo.
>
> ### Un poco del pasado
>
> El primer equipo con el que trabajó fue una computadora **[AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AST_Research)** y que recuerda que esperaba mucho para que la computadora encienda, se enfríe del sobre procesamiento que hacía para luego cargar sus juegos en los **[emuladores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulador)**. Extraña mucho ese equipo puesto que fue con él que pudo desarrollar más su afición hacia las computadoras, desarmándolo para arreglarlo y dándole mantenimiento hasta donde se podía con pocos recursos.
>
> Para la época universitaria se consiguió una mejor computadora que él mismo ensambló. En ella desarrollaba sus primeros programas en **[Pascal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n))**, **[Borland Delphi](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi)** que enseñaban en la universidad, luego comenzó a estudiar C y C++ por su cuenta, un poco de C# y Java en la fórmula, y se dedicó un tiempo a estudiar y profundizar en algoritmos para concursar en el **[ACM ICPC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competici%C3%B3n_Internacional_Universitaria_ACM_de_Programaci%C3%B3n)** representando a su universidad en los equipos locales.
>
> ### El presente
>
> **[Participo en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza?tab=profile)** desde fines del 2011, sobretodo en la etiqueta [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). El sitio me llamó la atención porque es una plataforma para aprender bastante. Donde encontré mi nicho de aprendizaje fue al responder preguntas, así estuviese equivocado, puesto que eso me ayudaba a reforzar las ideas que ya conocía o a investigar y aprender sobre algo que me resultaría interesante. Inclusive, revisando preguntas que no sabía cómo responder aprendí cosas que luego las utilizaría en mi trabajo.
>
> Me considero agnóstico a las tecnologías y lenguajes de programación. Utilizo el lenguaje y las tecnologías más apropiados para resolver los problemas. Trabajo principalmente con Java y tecnologías libres. Conozco un poco de C#, JavaScript, **[IBM Informix 4gl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Informix-4GL)** y otros lenguajes más por allí. Me fascinan los retos, trato de resolver los desafíos de **[Code Fights](https://codefights.com)** y los problemas de **[Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net)**. Ando investigando de todo un poco para estar al día con la tecnología. Actualmente me interesa aprender sobre **[Big Data](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data)** y desarrollo para móviles de manera nativa.
>
> Me siento muy agradecido con @JuanM por esta oportunidad. Daré todo de mí para apoyar a que la comunidad continúe su rumbo hacia su madurez y que albergue conocimiento de calidad y que ayude a nuestros compañeros de programación hispano hablantes. Al igual que **[@Konamiman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman)**, es la primera vez que seré moderador, así que pido su colaboración para que todos hagamos de este no solo un sitio sino un espacio en internet donde podamos fomentar el conocimiento y demostrar que hacemos más que solo escribir código.
>
> Por favor continúen publicando preguntas, respuestas, comentarios y se portan bien. Si no luego les daré su jalón de orejas.

Por favor ayúdenme a darle una gran bienvenida a Luiggi Mendoza, ¡nuestro segundo moderador!

Comment: ¡Excelente adición, felicidades Luiggi! Solo espero que ahora que eres moderador no me moderes mucho en el chat jejeje

Comment: Felicidades señor diamante!!!!!!

Comment: _Donde encontré mi nicho de aprendizaje fue al responder preguntas_ me identifico con eso... la mejor de las vibras para ti @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Felicitaciones @LuiggiMendoza! Siempre es un gusto tener gente tan comprometida con el sitio como moderadores

Comment: Felicitaciones! :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias compañeros :D

Comment: Felicitaciones Luiggi

Comment: @César yo soy uno de los Owners del chat :)

Comment: Felicitaciones @LuiggiMendoza, espero que cumplas el compromiso de hacer crecer a esta comunidad

Comment: Felicitaciones @LuiggiMendoza! Esa caja misteriosa fue la llave de entrada a muchos desarrolladores. Saludos y muchos éxitos!

Comment: Felicidades luigii!

Comment: @JuanM Acabo de ver este post, solo me pregunto porque las elecciones de moderador no se realizan democrática mente, saludos.

Comment: @Elenasys Al empezar un nuevo sitio, el gerente de comunidades elige a los nuevos moderadores hasta que se gradúe el sitio y no este en versión beta. Después de ese tiempo, las nominaciones empezarán. 

Comment: @JuanM Gracias por la información Juan, sinceramente pensé que habíamos pasado la etapa Beta!, bien, seguramente se graduara ya que tenemos buenas estadísticas, saludos!

Comment: @Elenasys Todavía no, pero para ahí vamos! Gusto en platicar de nuevo contigo.

Comment: Las nuevas generaciones vienen pisando fuerte... bienvenido, tu trabajo aquí no va a ser demasiado estresante, al menos por ahora :-)

Comment: Felicitaciones :)

Comment: Felicitaciones @LuiggiMendoza ! recién veo este post.