# ¿Para cuando unas elecciones para tener un moderador moderado?

Tags: discusión, soporte, moderación

Pues me refiero en concreto al usuario que, en mi opinion, no actua como  moderador @Luggi Mendoza cuyas actitudes similares a la de [este post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/788/cual-es-la-verdadera-intenci%C3%B3n-con-las-puntuaciones-negativas/799#799) estoy harto de confrontar:

He estabo buscando ejemplos de su mala actitud pero al ser moderador, enganchada que tiene conmigo, enganchada que borra

No digo que no tenga razon en algunas cosas, simplemente opino que su actitud como moderador es muy reprobable, hablando mal, insultando como los comentarios del primer link, creando confrontaciones y usando sus privilegios (en mi opinion) para su propio beneficio (o en el que cree que el foro debería llevar —ignorando las actuales normas del foro), al contrario que los otros dos moderadores, [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) y [konamiman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman) cuya actitud y colaboracion me parece de lo mas adecuada.

Con todo esto, y debido a que [su designacion (como buen foro en español que somos) fué a dedo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/519/conozcan-a-nuestro-segundo-moderador-luiggi-mendoza) y no por elecciones:

> Me gustaron las ideas y la energía que proporciono y me quede pensando que seria una buena adición al equipo.

**¿Para cuando unas elecciones para tener un moderador *moderado* y no un usuario que no mantiene la calma como debería ser su responsabilidad?**

---

## EDIT:

Después de postear esto, se ha puesto a increparme en la conversación que lo ha originado, me ha atacado en 2 comentarios a los cuales he respondido y cuando ha visto esta pregunta los ha borrado aludiendo que eran muy conversadores cuando ha sido él quien los ha generado. **precisamente esa actitud es a la que me refiero**

---

## EDIT2:

Y como en la anterior conversación, ha vuelto a hacerlo en ésta, me increpa con comentarios, le contesto y despues lo borra y encima me dice que le escriba en privado, **como si fueran problemas personales!!!**, lo siento pero me parece una muy buena metafora de la *muchedumbre* lo que este *moderador* hace con sus privilegios.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

## EDIT3:

Estoy de acuerdo con los que pedíais edición para presentar los argumentos de una manera más reposada, lo he intentado hacer mejor, disculpas porque no he podido cambiarlo hasta hoy porque [la app movil tiene un bug](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/821/bug-app-movil-con-etiquetas-obligatorias) que no permite edición con alguno de los tags obligatorios.

---

## EDIT4

> RESPUESTA A JUAN

@juan, si miras mis acciones verás que siempre he marcado tanto los comentarios como las acciones que no creo adecuadas, tanto de luiggi como de otros usuarios. *otra cosa es como se resuelve esto cuando la persona marcada es la que resuelve el marcador...*

Si te fijas con este tema solo he saltado cuando se ha metido con la comunidad llamandonos *muchedumbre*, actuacion que, a mi parecer **es intolerable *por definición* en un moderador**.

En cuanto a lo de borrar los comentarios cuando son conversadores / ofensivos, yo tambien estoy de acuerdo, y si miras mi historial de reportes verás que soy bastante activo y que no he hecho nada pese a que no estoy de acuerdo en bastantes de las decisiones, pero entiendo que

- un moderador tiene que saber cual es su posición porque **siempre es moderador**
- no debe ni puede generar discordia, **sinó resolverla**
- si el caso se diera, nunca debe actuar él mismo como moderador en las acciones en las que está involucrado como usuario o en las que ha sido reportado una de sus acciones.

Cuando un usuario con poder y esta actitud empieza a coger confianza y seguridad es cuando degenera en este comportamiento que varios hemos visto y denunciado (sin éxito) y que con este post intento visibilizar y hacer todo lo posible por acabar con él [comportamiento], para beneficio de la comunidad.

---

## CONCLUSIÓN PERSONAL

**Debido a esta actitud, y sintiendolo mucho por los [javeros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) y porque desde el principio he trabajado porque esta comunidad crezca y lo he hecho sinceramente, mi colaboración en el foro en español se acaba hasta que no se presente una solución a esta petición.**

Comment: Entiendo que hasta que [no salgamos de la beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) no habrá elecciones. @JuanM ya lo mencionó [aquí](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/519/conozcan-a-nuestro-segundo-moderador-luiggi-mendoza#comment1264_519).

Comment: Paralelamente yo lo que sí que veo es que no estaría de más tener *otro* moderador. Luiggi es el **único** moderador del sitio SO en español oficial. Y si pudiera ser con horario de España, aún mejor, muchas veces estoy des de las 8 de la mañana (hora española) hasta las 4-6 de la tarde (hora española) en la que no hay ningún moderador en el sitio.

Comment: Curiosamente estaba pensando en hacer una pregunta similar, creo que necesitamos al menos más de un moderador, con el fin que el "poder" esté un poco más descentralizado y se tenga más de un punto de vista a la hora de decidir si los "demás usuarios" tienen la razón o no a la hora de enviar reportes, votar o no por cierres de preguntas, etc.

Comment: @Miquel como pongo en mi pregunta, konamiman es mod oficial (antes que Luiggi) y ademas lo es tambien de SO... Supongo que no lo conoces porque mantiene un nivel bajo con actitud más sobria y moderada IMHO actua como corresponde a un buen mod

Comment: @JordiCastilla Sí que conozco a konamiman pero creo que sólo actúa de moderador en meta. De hecho, si miras la [página oficial de moderadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) sólo aparece Luiggi.

Comment: No sé como funciona, pero no me sorprendería que Konamiman hubiese perdido su rol de moderador de SOes cuando empezó a trabajar en SE (al pasar a ser moderador de todos los sitios en general).

Comment: Suscribo en todo lo dicho y para que a solicitud sea coherente, **se deberían eliminar los adjetivos calificativos**. La solicitud es justa, pero debe ser objetiva. LuigiMendoza _es_ moderador, nada de "supuesto". Y por supuesto llamarlo __hoolingan__ le resta valor a una solicitud que, por otro lado, es perfectamente pertinente.

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que @toledano intentemos mantener un discurso respetuoso.

Comment: La solicitud de un nuevo moderador es muy válida, pero es, necesariamente de alto nivel. Si unos se llaman _muchedumbre_ o _autómata_ y otro contesta con _hooligan_, sigan así. Hay que tener altura de miras y saber cuando pasar a un estadio superior.

Comment: Objetivamente, yo apoyo la moción de que se necesita otro moderador. Fuera de eso, si tienes un problema a nivel personal conmigo, mi correo está en la descripción de usuario, allí puedes contactarme y resolver esos problemas **fuera del sitio, sin roles de moderador/usuario**. Si no tienes nada que conversar porque "no hay ningún problema", entonces sería bueno dejar los adjetivos (buenos o malos) de lado y centrarnos en el bienestar del sitio, el cual ha sido mi motor desde que el sitio inició como alfa.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Te recomiendo que cierres SO hasta mañana :) Creo que los aires estan caldeados y has contribuido muchísimo en este comunidad. Date 1 día y verás las cosas distintas, pero sobretodo, ¡no nos abandones!

Comment: @miquel, lo siento, pero con lo que me acaba de hacer ha colmado el vaso, mi colaboracion en es.SO se ha acabado mientras esto no se solucione, lo siento

Comment: @JordiCastilla Entiendo tu frustración y puedo comprender tu postura. SO en general es un sitio donde los usuarios son diversos y con opiniones muy diferentes. Sin embargo, la mayoría de los usuarios quieren llevar el sitio a que tenga éxito, y en ese sentido, tu participación (aunque sea sólo en Meta), es valiosa

Comment: @Lamak en meta no voy a dejarlo, pero inicio una *huelga de hambre* en lo que corresponde al foro técnico. Dedicaré mi tiempo libre y esfuerzos a otras comunidades evidentemente mejor administradas

Comment: @JordiCastilla Me parece perfectamente válido, incluso diría que en estos momentos lo que SO en español más necesita es una comunidad *coherente*

Comment: con todo respeto a las dos partes, sin animo de ofender y siendo de lo mas neutral pues no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre el tema y sobre este tipo de foros, me parece que todo esto es demasiado infantil, es mejor enfocar toda esas vibras en algo que nos ayude a mejorar como comunidad y no atacarnos unos a otros, sin decir **reitero** que alguno de los dos tenga o no la razón

Comment: Jordi, es una falta de respeto hablarle así a cualquier persona y/o de cualquier persona, presente o no. ¿Eres un niño? lo digo con la mejor buena onda, por que no cabe en ninguna cabeza que esta es una forma de resolver problemas. Mi consejo, tomate el tiempo de pensar bien que vas a decir y argumenta contra las acciones y decisiones, no contra las personas. Esto es algo aproximado de lo que quiero decir: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumento_ad_hominem, Luego, vuelve a proponer la destitución de @LuiggiMendoza, Saludos.

Comment: @rnd muy elegante pero incorrecto, no estoy presentando falacias sino hechos contrastados. Ademas creo que el sistema de votos del foro responde por si solo, he dejado clara mi opinion, si quieres presentar argumentos reales eres bienvenido. Yo lo siento, pero no puedo callarme contra las injusticias y por tanto, cuando me rebelo, mi mensaje es duro, puedes pensar que infantil, pero ni falacia ni falso. Tambien me gustaria que opinaras sobre lo QUE digo aparte de COMO lo digo. Un saludo

Comment: Mi opinion es que este sitio es para desarrollar la cabeza, si se cierra, si no se cierra, si se vota, si no se vota.. no me interesa mucho, me interesa que el sitio crezca, así mas gente desarrolla la cabeza y evoluciona la sociedad, que tan mal esta con tanta agresividad suelta.

Comment: y no quise decir que estabas mintiendo, sino que no va a ninguna parte este post. Por que pegarle al moderador, es olvidarse que hay bajada de linea desde atrás y muy, pero muy, mala comunicación.

Comment: @Jordi Ojalá recapacites y sigamos viendo tus aportes en SOes.. Dicho esto, es casi imposible ser objetivo con tu publicación subjetiva. Ojalá pudieses editarla para que sea objetiva y sin los argumentos que para mí le restan todo valor. Por otro lado, respecto a tu 2do parrafo: "*su mala actitud* [...] *he podido recuperar* [...] http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9592/127 ", creo que no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con que sea ♦, en cambio creo que es una discusión entre 2 usuarios expertos, de la cual me he enriquecido leyendo recién. Es un usuario además de ♦ y no veo que haya moderado ahí

Comment: Qué cosa tan lamentable a donde ha llegado esto. No suscribo ni a los comentarios despectivos del moderador ni al autor de esta publicación. Yo supongo que la gente que comenta y publica aquí tiene un mínimo sentido del respeto y la argumentación y no los encuentro por ningún lado, de ninguna de las partes. Muy penoso todo esto.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Totalmente de acuerdo con tu opinión voto a favor

Comment: @JordiCastilla gracias por la edición. Espero que todo esté más tranquilo :) Se extrañan tus contribuciones!

Comment: @JordiCastilla  se extrañan tus contribuciones y las criticas a mis respuestas haha, en verdad me gustaría que personas como tu estuvieran presentes en esta comunidad, un saludo!

Comment: A pesar que el tema y los datos y hechos referidos me parecem muy pertinentes (fecha de las elecciones de moderador, referencias, etc.) algunos de elementos de la forma no me parecen apropiados en particular los calificativos personales los cuales no son necesarios para tratar el tema de forma objetiva y clara.

Answer (score 14):

Voto **en contra** de la petición de eliminar al actual moderador, pero...

1. Le solicito al moderador **ofrecer excusas públicas** por sus ya conocidas declaraciones y comentarios despectivos y atrevidos frente a los usuarios de esta comunidad. [**No en la sala de chat**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/796/un-gran-poder-conlleva-una-gran-responsabilidad/805?noredirect=1#comment1847_805) (porque usted no ofendió a los usuarios del chat sino a toda la comunidad)
2. Sugiero la posibilidad de solicitar la inclusión de más moderadores (elegidos, a dedo, no sé): personas capaces (al igual que el moderador actual) pero que sí tengan tacto, respeto por los usuarios del sitio y sobre todo capacidad de aceptar y corregir sus errores por el bien y crecimiento de SOes.

Answer (score 9):

Sucribo la solicitud. No estoy de acuerdo con los adjetivos, pero *en mi opinión personalísima* las razones son válidad y he sido testigo del comportamiento reclamado.

Voto a favor.

Comment: Se expusieron demasiados argumentos y estoy un poco confundido. ¿Te podría pedir si aclarás bien explícito a favor de qué estás votando? Por ejemplo, ¿estás votando a favor de que haya un nuevo moderador, que ayude y complemente la tarea de Luiggi?

Comment: Hubo muchas ediciones y comentarios. Pero estoy a favor de remover al moderador actual y elegir a otro.

Answer (score 8):

Cuando un grupo de personas se juntan a discutir un tema de el cual existe mucha pasión se encontrarán oportunidades para no estar de acuerdo en varias cosas. Esto es normal y anticipado.  Lo que nos destacará como comunidad son los pasos siguientes - ¿cómo continuaremos adelante?

Para empezar, esta publicación no empezó bien. El atacar a la gente de manera abierta nunca se aprecia y disminuye el contenido.  Mejor hubiera sido el contactarme personalmente citando las razones de los malos sentimientos. Así, se pudiera resolver esto de manera eficaz y discreta. Entiendo que la culpa puede estar en los dos lados pero mejor hubiese sido que el autor hubiera tomado una postura diferente en vez de pagar "ojo por ojo." Pero bueno, sucedió esto ya y podemos todos aprender de ello. Recuerden que el atacar a los moderadores de esta manera no es productivo y no resultará en el los cambios deseados. Ellos están aquí para ayudar a la comunidad y lo hacen gratuitamente y sin caprichos.

Para dar un poco de contexto, los moderadores del sitio - Konamiman y Luiggi Mendoza, fueron escogidos por mi, el gerente de la comunidad, al empezar este proyecto.  Ambos moderadores mostraron interés, habilidad, conocimiento de la plataforma y deseo de ayudar a moderar el sitio. Uno de ellos, Konamiman, fue contratado y ahora trabaja al lado mío aquí en Stack Overflow. Esto nos dejo a Luiggi y a mi como moderadores del sitio solamente. Créanme que el moderar este sitio no es cosa simple.  Se requieren muchas habilidades y mucha experiencia para poder apoyar a la comunidad como se debe. El sitio es nuevo y estamos aprendiendo a tratarnos entre todos. Necesitamos tener paciencia los unos con los otros, especialmente en casos como estos donde lo más normal es atacar en defensa propia.

Miren, todos los que venimos al sitio estamos aquí porque necesitamos algo: (1) la solución a un problema o (2) el querer ayudar a otros a mejorar sus habilidades. Todos venimos aquí porque queremos hacerlo. No venimos para argumentar o causar problemas.  Pero, como ya saben, las interacciones entre personas dejan la puerta abierta a la discordia y a las malas interpretaciones. Es cosa de la naturaleza de la comunicación y por eso necesitamos estar en guardia.

He leído los argumentos del autor de esta pregunta y pienso que tiene razón en sentirse agredido pero también vi los comentarios eliminados y estoy de acuerdo con la decision de Luiggi de removerlos. Yo hubiera hecho lo mismo. Esto huele a discordia entre dos personas solamente y se pudiera haber resuelto en privado.

Luiggi tiene un puesto de autoridad como moderador y merece el respeto de nuestra comunidad. Si existen quejas contra el, lo mejor es de hablar con el en privado y si no resulta en la satisfacción de los participantes, se me debe incluir en las charlas que sigan. No removeremos a Luiggi como moderador.  El es una parte integral de lo que estamos formando y lo apoyare en lo que pueda.  Tal vez necesite ayudarle más a mejorar sus habilidades como moderador, pero eso ya es otro tema.  Tengo confianza en Luiggi y se ha demostrado como una persona de carácter amigable y profesional (aunque últimamente me he dado cuenta de estas acciones recientes) pero eso es de esperar siendo que todos somos seres humanos y tendemos a fallar de vez en cuando también. Lo mismo opino del autor de este post.  Creo que sus intenciones son las compartidas - de ayudar a crecer el sitio. Pero hubo un choque y necesitamos arreglar eso.

Invito a que los dos se pongan en contacto y se aclare esto entre ellos. Si les gustaría tener una 3ra parte presente, con gusto los acompaño.

En fin, sigamos con lo demás - y para contestar la pregunta original:

> ¿Para cuando unas elecciones para tener un moderador *moderado* .....?

Ya lo tenemos....pero me imagino que la pregunta es de cuando agregar a otra persona.

Creo que se aproxima el tiempo de invitar a otro moderador al sitio. No tendremos un voto para moderadores hasta no graduarnos como un sitio normal de la red de Stack Exchange pero empezaré a investigar más sobre lo de un moderador nuevo en los próximos días.

Comment: +1. Luiggi ha hecho un buen trabajo de moderador (des de mi punto de vista) pero creo que la comunidad va creciendo y según lo que comenta Mariano en su respuesta considero que agregar otro moderador sería beneficioso para la comunidad debido a la cantidad de trabajo que existe (no porqué Luiggi no sea capaz de hacerlo, por qué lo hace **todo**). Me gustaría añadir que si el nuevo moderador puede tener una franja horaria distinta mejor para la comunidad :D

Comment: @juan tienes mi respuesta en el `#edit4`, era demasiado larga para un comentario... `:P`

Comment: @JordiCastilla Aprecio tus comentarios y gracias por mantenerlos amigables. He hablado con Luiggi y me pondré la tarea de ayudarle a manejar estas situaciones con más cuidado en el futuro.  Creo que tienes buenas intenciones y espero que puedas volver a integrarte de nuevo como un usuario valioso.

Answer (score 6):

Buen día, hace un par de días vi esta pregunta, me llamo de sobremanera la atención, se genero cuando estaba de vacaciones, pero me gustaría agregar mi punto de vista.

La función de un **moderador** consiste  en:

> administrar de una forma controlada contribuciones realizadas por
>   una comunidad, en este caso los usuarios.

pero existe algo importante y tal vez es **una de las reglas principales que debe tener en cuenta un moderador y esto es *evitar la censura*.**

Solo puedo comentar que gracias a las personas se forma una sociedad, gracias a las personas que en ocasiones no realizamos las cosas de una forma la cual con concuerda con las ideas de una persona y no le agrada, no quiere decir que de alguna manera o no contribuyamos a su crecimiento, y más aún cuando **nosotros los usuarios no rompemos las reglas de la comunidad.**

Si se están rompiendo las reglas el moderador debe:

- Aplicar sanciones a usuarios infractores.
- Organizar y dirigir a los usuarios para el correcto uso del sitio.

Por experiencia puedo comentar que ser miembro de una comunidad es infinitamente diferente a administrarla o moderarla, se debe tener en detalle presente la conciliación, el respeto. Sobra decir que no se pueden admitir características de soberbia, falta de tacto al manejar situaciones que pueden llevar a usuarios a dejar la comunidad, al contrario, los usuarios se deben sentir atraídos a esta y colaborar en la misma.

Hace tiempo cuando se asigno un moderador, pero bien, se me respondió que esta votación democrática se realizaría cuando el sitio dejara de ser beta.

Hasta el día de hoy no se elimino al moderador, y mi postura sería neutral ya que por alguna razón Juan lo designo, pero **espero en un futuro no tan lejano se realicen votaciones democráticas para seleccionar a los moderadores.**

---

un poco de humor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En cuanto tengamos nuestra graduación, se seleccionarán los moderadores del sitio por forma democrática tal y como se have por costumbre en nuestra red.  Los moderadores actuales tendrán oportunidad de volver a ser moderadores si les interesa siempre y cuando la comunidad los escoja de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, aclaro que voy a ignorar todos los puntos subjetivos de la pregunta. Si bien tengo una opinión personal muy formada acerca de este tema (*-y no es lo que  estás pensando, y totalmente dispuesto a conversarlo en otra publicación u otro ámbito donde no esté en juego lo que se discute acá*), hay un punto muchísimo más primordial que, en mi opinión tiene un peso significativo por sobre cualquier otra cosa. Creo que, sin importar quién dijo qué, o cómo debería ser, o cómo se debería proceder, supera a cualquier argumento, y es lo que voy a exponer.

---

## Voto EN CONTRA de remover al moderador actual.

<sup>Y no voy a emitir opinión de si se debería elegir a alguien más que complemente, no en esta publicación.</sup>

Motivos de mayor peso:

1. **Atenta contra la viabilidad del sitio.**
   Un cambio de esta índole es lo peor que podríamos llegar a realizar en un sitio en beta. Pensar en sacar a quien ya tiene meses de experiencia en la moderación y que, por el trabajo realizado en estos meses, podemos asumir que tiene un contacto ya pulido con otros moderadores y conoce lo bueno y lo malo en la revisión de la mayoría de nosotros (usuarios frecuentes), sería retroceder muchos pasos en la evolución del sitio, tanto que hasta creo que peligrarían las chances de que sigamos existiendo como comunidad. Además, implicaría perder todas las lecciones aprendidas hasta ahora en la gestión de Stack Overflow en español.
2. **Se argumenta sobre las formas, sin considerar el trabajo realizado.**
   Uno puede coincidir o no con las opiniones expuestas por Luiggi, o con algunas decisiones puntuales tomadas en la moderación, pero no podemos dejar de considerar el trabajo que se viene realizando. Leí argumentos acerca de las opiniones expresadas y el cómo fueron expresadas, pero no acerca del trabajo realizado, de la moderación en sí. Para contextualizar, comparemos la tarea de moderación versus los sitios "hermanos".
   [image: Cantidad de posts activos/mes/moderador]
   <sup>Fuente: [SOru](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/529765/soru-number-of-active-posts-last-month-per-mod), [SOes](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/529759/soes-number-of-active-posts-last-month-per-mod), [SOpt](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/529763/sopt-number-of-active-posts-last-month-per-mod), [SOjp](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/529767/soja-number-of-active-posts-last-month-per-mod).</sup>
   Claramente hay una diferencia significativa en el volúmen de publicaciones que 1 moderador tiene que tratar diariamente versus SO en japonés y portugués. Y si bien el sitio ruso tiene un valor cercano, aparentemente recién implementaron auditorías de revisión (*review audits*) porque el problema que tienen es el opuesto, que se acepta todo incluso si es de mala calidad <sup>([fuente](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3563/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82))</sup>.
3. **La primer reacción no puede ser remover sin antes buscar mejorar.**
   En el caso de estar en desacuerdo con una acción u opinión de moderación, creo que deberíamos buscar discutirlo con seriedad en meta, intentando llegar a un consenso en las formas empleadas. No vi una publicación de peso que apunte a eso, sólo comentarios (míos también). Y si la hubo y no la vi, quizás deberíamos haberlo planteado de otra forma para considerarlo en serio. Todos acá somos humanos, incluyendo a Luiggi (y excluyendo al script que usaron los autómatas -jaja). Si hay algo que podríamos mejorar, espero que primero intentemos hacerlo. Creo que seríamos una comunidad muy poco evolucionada si no optáramos por plantear un problema antes de tomar una acción. Y esto, de nuevo, creo que nos marcaría un retroceso enorme, alejándonos de una posible graduación.

Comment: Soy un ferviente creyente del enfoque basado en datos para la toma de decisiones. Y las gráficas bonitas siempre atraen. Pero lo que demuestra la gráfica es que necesitamos **dos moderadores más** para llegar al nivel del sitio en portugués. Por supuesto que no indica si es un buen trabajo de moderación o no. Los puntos uno y tres, son opiniones sin el comentado _factual approach_, y que sin embargo deben tenerse en altísima estima (por cierto que te considero un usuario de gran valía para la comunidad). Estoy convencido que se debe tomar una decisión. Ignorar este tema si sería un retroceso.

Comment: @toledano Es cierto todo lo que comentás, agregando que el gráfico no muestra calidad pero sí cantidad. Omití dar juicio de valor sobre *agregar* moderadores porque creo que no es el tema de fondo que plantea Jordi. El 1er punto no puedo contrastarlo porque no tengo acceso a datos (o desconozco). Es una opinión que intenta ser lo más objetiva posible (y como toda opinión...). Pero el 3er punto, creo que sí se sustenta en el hecho de que no hay (o no encontré) publicaciones que intenten mejorar esta condición... Mi visión: no estoy de acuerdo con destruir lo trabajado (sí a reverlo).

Comment: "quien tiene un contacto ya pulido con otros moderadores" ¿con cuáles otros?

Comment: @dwarandae Estoy asumiéndolo como parte del trabajo. Modifiqué la respuesta para dejarlo por explícito.

Comment: Ya estamos en 5822 preguntas por mes.

Comment: @Rubén Estás sugiriendo un 3er moderador? Jajaja

Answer (score -1):

[Para ahora.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) La elección final empezará el 28 de Julio de 2017 y durará 4 días.

Si no quieres que vuelva a pasar lo mismo ahora tienes la oportunidad de hacer algo al respecto: votar.
Quien pudiendo hacerlo no vota tiene poco derecho moral a quejarse de lo que hagan o dejen de hacer los moderadores.
Lee las [respuestas de los candidatos a 10 preguntas seleccionadas.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2478/2017-elecci%C3%B3n-de-moderador-cuestionario)
Hazles otras preguntas o habla con ellos en el [chat de las elecciones](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61769/elecciones-2017-soes).
Revisa lo que han hecho como usuarios normales. ¿Han sido activos en meta? ¿En las colas de revisión? ¿En los reportes?
[Visita sus presentaciones.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1)

Y después vota. Despues de estas eleciones, para bien or para mal, tendremos lo que nos merecemos.