# Bug app móvil con etiquetas obligatorias acentuadas

Tags: bug, app-móvil

pues quería editar [el polémico post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/800/para-cuando-unas-elecciones-para-tener-un-moderador-moderado?noredirect=1&lq=1) durante el fin de semana y al no tener acceso a ninguna máquina quise hacerlo desde el móvil, el problema es que al enviar los cambios, me aparece siempre el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver hay un par de errores:

- Traducción
- No deja editar aunque tenga una de las etiquetas necesarias (eso sí, por lo que he probado, entiendo solamente fallan con las las etiquetas que tienen acento)

Comment: Creo que podrías publicarlo en [meta.se] como [bug] [mobile-app]

Comment: @Mariano lo he pensado, pero como ya ha habido [otras discusiones en el foro con los acentos de las etiquetas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/etiquetas-con-accentos-no-funcionan-por-lo-menos-en-meta?rq=1) y al tener también el tema de la traducción he decidido ponerlo aqui y ver que nos dicen `:P`