# Demos la bienvenida a nuestros 3 moderadores oficiales

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

[¡Felicidades a nuestros 3 moderadores oficiales!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/08/01/felicidades-nuestros-3-moderadores-oficiales/)

Después de una larga jornada para abrir el sitio y para graduarnos, hemos cumplido con el último paso - el de instalar a nuestros moderadores oficiales por medio de una [elección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1).

Es con mucha alegría y con mucho entusiasmo que les presento a:

[image: Alvaro Montoro]
[image: Jorgesys]
[image: lois6b]

¡Felicidades muchachos!

Comment: Para los que no estén familiarizados con la labor de los moderadores en este sitio favor de leer [Una teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/65).

Comment: Bravo muchachos!!!!!

Comment: Felicidades por tener el respaldo de la comunidad

Comment: ¡¡Felicidades!!

Comment: A la bio! A la bao! A la bim bom ba! Los moderadores! Los moderadores! Ra! Ra! Ra!

Comment: Felicidades a los ganadores y muchas gracias a todos los que se han presentado

Comment: Enhorabuena a los 3!!! Ahora toca hacer un gran trabajo como han hecho nuestros anteriores moderadores! A trabajar duro y a disfrutar del nuevo cargo!

Comment: Enhorabuena a los tres.

Comment: Enhorabuena a los nuevos moderadores, se espera mucho de vosotros! Y a los que dejan el puesto, muchas gracias por el tiempo y la dedicación.

Comment: Por una mejor comunidad /o/ :D

Comment: ¡Venga vamos! con todo el power 2.0!!! Éxitos hermanos :D gracias por todo el apoyo a la comunidad :D

Comment: Enhorabuena a los tres seleccionados y a todos a los que optaron al puesto. A seguir creciendo como comunidad!

Answer (score 19):

Y a Ezequiel y a Fredy muchas gracias por su tiempo y su esfuerzo. Gracias fredyfx y gracias ArtEze.

Y un reconocimiento muy especial a Luigi Mendoza que nos aguanto desde el inicio.

Gracias Luigi.

Comment: Gracias, siempre fuiste justo, aprobando y rechazando mis ediciones sugeridas con buen criterio.

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir :D

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza J no nos aguantó desde el inicio, no como moderador. Como moderador nos aguantó desde el [23 de marzo de 2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/519/301)

Answer (score 16):

Estoy muy contento de tener a nuestros primeros moderadores electos.

Muchísimas felicitaciones a Álvaro, Jorgesys y lois6b. Totalmente merecido por todo lo que ya hicieron por moderar el sitio, y todo lo que se les viene! :-)

Éxitos a los 3 y el mejor de los deseos para que SOes crezca de la mejor manera.

Answer (score 12):

Dejo algunos recuerdos que tuve en el chat:

1. [Álvaro Montoro](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32321769#32321769) (rescato la tilde de su nombre):

> **ArtEze:** No es por semestre, cada año se puede anotar como 8 materias máximo, y en total debo aprobar 40 para ser ingeniero.
>
> **Pedro Miguel Pimienta Morales:** a bueno. @AlvaroMontoro que mas, @ArtEze es nuevo por aqui.
>
> **Alvaro Montoro:** Hola :)
>
> **ArtEze:** Woow! Me saludó uno de los grandes.

2. [Jorgesys (Elenasys)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32722452#32722452)

> **Elenasys:** @fredyfx Hola amigo Fredyfx excelente y tu quetal!
>
> **ArtEze**: @Elenasys Hola, creo que es la primera vez que te veo por acá.
>
> **FredyFX:** @Elenasys feliz de la vida :D
>
> **Elenasys:** Hola si ArtEze
>
> **FredyFX:** @Elenasys es el top 1 de usuarios en SOes :D
>
> **ArtEze:** Sí, increíble.

3. [lois6b](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=37775384#37775384): Un día se me ocurrió hacer una imagen y lo puse ahí.

[image: Trauma, Juan M, fredyfx, lois6b, Mariano y Victor Random]

Comment: bonitos recuerdos en la sala de chat :D Recién veo la imagen, está muy cheeere! gracias bro!

Answer (score 11):

Enhorabuena a los 3. Lo difícil empieza ahora. Confiamos en que harán un buen trabajo, y estaremos atentos para ayudar en lo posible (y tambien para darles un poco de leña si pensamos que se han equivocado, de eso se trata ;) ).

Creo que todos lo merecen y en lo personal, aqui estoy para lo que necesiten.

Answer (score 9):

Además, si no me equivoco @jachguate creó la propuesta en Area51 hace exactamente 5 años :)

¡Enhorabuena a todos!

Comment: Honor a quien honor merece, nuestro amigo Juan Castillo de Guatemala!. @jachguate

Answer (score 6):

En ocasiones como esta, es un placer decir:

¡Muchas facilidades!

Answer (score 3):

Vale! felicitaciones a todos por este hito! quedara marcado en discos magnéticos con lapices de silicio el día en que esta comunidad eligió sus primeros moderadores

Answer (score 3):

**Mil felicidades!! a los tres, en buena hora eh...**

Sabemos el trabajo es arduo y que no sera fácil pero tambien se sabe que lo haran bien, suerte y **muchas gracias** por el bien que hacen a la comunidad.

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente, gracias!!! han sido lo mejor que me pude encontrar

Answer (score 3):

Bienvenidos, esperamos que les vaya bien. abrazos.

Answer (score 2):

Enhorabuena a los tres, gracias a gente como vosotros este sitio es un lugar brillante de ayuda en nuestro día a día.